# Laravel 5 joining multiple tables

Tags: sql, join, laravel-5

I am having real problems joining tables in Laravel.

I can join 2 tables but as soon as I try to join a third, i get no data

```
class Main extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'main';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function test() 
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Test', 'id', 'id');
    }

    public function row() 
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Row', 'id', 'id');
    }
}

class Test extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'test';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function main() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Main', 'id', 'id');
    }

    public function rows() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Row', 'id', 'id');
    }
}

class Row extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'row';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function main() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Main', 'id', 'id');
    }

    public function rows() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Test', 'id', 'id');
    }
}
```

I've added this to my Main model to run a query. This will output the 2 tables

```
public function scopeGetPart($query, somefield)
{
    return $query->with('test.main')
        ->where('somefield', somefield);
}
```

This works when i run it through phpMyAdmin. I want to write this the Laravel way

```
SELECT * FROM
    main
        INNER JOIN test ON
            main.id = test.id
        INNER JOIN row ON
            main.id = row.id
                AND main.my_field = row.my_field
WHERE somefield = 103288
```

Answer (score 0):

Without running your code, have you tried `$main->with('test.rows')`? This should fetch the tests of a main instance with the rows of the test.

Comment: All my other queries and joins work perfectly, What about echoing the raw SQL so i can see what's run?

Answer (score 0):

I gave up with Eloquent as it was causing problems and used this instead which works how i wanted

```
DB::table('main')
    ->join('test', 'main.id', '=', 'test.id')
    ->join('row', function ($join) {
         $join->on('main.id', '=', 'row.id')
              ->whereRaw('main.my_field= row.my_field');
         })
    ->where('somefield', '103288');
```